# Best practices in defining Mocks in Moq when using Setup and Verify

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq

There are two patterns of `Setup(...)` and `Verify(...)`:

**Option 1**

```
// Define mock
_textTransformerMock = new Mock<ITextTransformer>();

// Setup with Any String
_textTransformerMock.Setup(t => t.Transform(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("transformed");
```

And when verify use this code:

```
_textTransformerMock.Verify(t => t.Transform(It.Is<string>(s => s == "input")), Times.Once);
```

**Option 2**

```
// Define mock
_textTransformerMock = new Mock<ITextTransformer>();

// Setup with the input string we expect
_textTransformerMock.Setup(t => t.Transform("input")).Returns("transformed");
```

And when verify use this code:

```
_textTransformerMock.Verify(t => t.Transform("input"), Times.Once);
```

---

My idea is option 1 is more generic and is usefull when this code is placed Setup from the unit-test, so that more single unit-tests can just override and provide different values.

Option 2 seems a bit locked in to me?

I hope someone can share their experiences.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite opinion-based, but here is my opinion.

There is no use to do:

```
t => t.Transform(It.Is<string>(s => s == "input")
```

since the overload of `==` used for strings is entirely equivalent to the default `EqualityComparer<string>`, namely ordinal case-sensitive comparison, so therefore the shorter:

```
t => t.Transform("input")
```

gives exactly the same result.

Otherwise it is cool to use `It.Is`, for example `It.Is<string>(s => s.StartsWith("in"))` or anything. It can be used for both `Setup` and `Verify`, of course.

Another example with `It.Is`, it is `It.Is((string s) => string.Equals(s, "input", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))`.

---

Other than that, the difference between the two examples is whether you `Setup` for **all** values of the argument, or you `Setup` only for the expected value of the argument. I like the latter (Option 2) better. Why setup Moq for all arguments if you expect only one argument to be relevant?

You could go even further and use a strict mock, that is:

```
_textTransformerMock = new Mock<ITextTransformer>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

This means that Moq will not accept any argument value for which no setup "matches". In that case you will get an exception if the code you are testing, sends unexpected arguments to your method.

That being said, `It.IsAny` can be very useful in cases where you cannot tell in advance which value will occur, or when you have no possibility to supply an object with the same value (for example for types with reference equality semantics (unlike `string`) where you cannot pass to Moq the same *instance* as the system under test will use).